# Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'contenteditable' is non-assignable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a library for emoticons but i am getting this error! http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=contenteditable i am using angular 1.2.x, the emoticons library is this one https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup/tree/gh-pages how can i solve this?

mi html

```
<div emoji-form emoji-message="emojiMessage">                    
    <textarea id="messageInput" ng-model="emojiMessage.messagetext" /></textarea>
    <button id="emojibtn">
        <i class="icon icon-emoji"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

my controller

$scope.emojiMessage={};

thanks for help

Comment: If i edit the input, and add some words i get the error

Answer (score 0):

Try correct your html where:

```
<textarea id="messageInput" ng-model="emojiMessage.messagetext" /></textarea>
```

should be:

```
<textarea id="messageInput" ng-model="emojiMessage.messagetext"></textarea>
```

By:

`<textarea></textarea>` **without self-close**.

Comment: I did it and it is not working, I am getting the error!

Comment: Can you make any live demo by plunker/jsfeddle/codepen? Not very sure about your plugin version or any other possibiliby.